# Rails current_user controller check and then render slightly different views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I simply want the simplest solution to check if the user is the current user and based on the answer to render a view slightly different each time.

I have a route on `/users/:id` for each user which goes to the `show` of the `users_controller`

**Controller**

```
  def show    
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
     format.html #show.html.erb
    end
  end
```

I want to change the `show.html.erb` file in many places. I could try a `<% if @user == current_user %>` each time but I thought that would create a mess with a lengthy code or many partials.

I could also try to create a second view but I don't know if I'm working efficiently here:

**Controller**

```
  def show    
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user = current_user
      redirect_to show_is_current_user
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html #show.html.erb
      end
    end
  end

 def show_is_current_user 
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html #show_is_current_user.html.erb
   end
 end
```

Any more efficient solutions than the above?

Comment: You could keep both in the show action and just render the appropriate template.

Comment: Ok, so creating two different views is the best solution? Can you please write the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will render show.html.erb when users are viewing another user's profile and 
showself.html.erb when showing viewing their own profile:

```
  def show    
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user == current_user
        render "showself"
    end
  end
```